# How to serve multiple apps simultaneously with Panel/PyViz?

Tags: bokeh, pyviz, panel-pyviz

I've been exploring this problem of how to write a suite of small utilities but serve them up together. It's like writing multiple little .py files that each gives us a panel app, but I wanted to serve them up via a single Docker container with a single entrypoint.

Voila gives us the ability to serve up multiple notebooks by taking advantage of its jupyter extension; is something analogous possible with panel? For example, I'm wondering whether I could do `panel serve . [--options]` to serve up all .py files in a directory?

Answer (score 1):

h/t Philipp Rudiger, the lead developer of Panel, who gave pointed me to this answer:

> Use `panel serve src1.py nb1.ipynb ...` to serve multiple apps simultaneously.
>
> You might want to provide your own index page since the default bokeh one isn't too pretty.

Comment: Thanks for this. Did you coincidentally figure out how to modify the default Bokeh index page?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(. I'd be open to hearing if others have successfully done so!